# Rails not accepting JSON in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, passenger

I'm attempting to post a json object to my server, however for whatever reason it doesn't show up in production.

In development params.inspect yields

```
({"format"=>"json", "body"=>"Wtf", "api_key"=>"xxx", "action"=>"comment", "item_id"=>"496", "controller"=>"api"})
```

And in production I get

```
({"format"=>"json", "action"=>"comment", "controller"=>"api"})
```

The only difference in the two environments is that I run passenger/nginx in production. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It sure looks like what you think you are sending and what is actually getting sent are different things.  You could try using Wireshark to verify what exactly is getting sent to your server.

Comment: That was one of the first things I suspected, but it isn't the case. I setup a second production environment without passenger and everything is working properly... which means I'm still at a loss as to what's broken.

Comment: Um, it sounds like:
with passenger = broken
without passenger = works

Using Wireshark in the environment *with* passenger will help you localize the problem.